# Windows Service application hangs

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, timer

Background:
- Running Window Server 2008 R2.
- The servers has been patched with all the recent updates.
- Server is running 5 services built in .NET 3.5 and all of these services use timers to check database on repeated basis (mostly every 10 seconds).
- These services are not CPU/RAM intensive.
- Server doesn't have any performace and resources issues or bottlenecks.

For most of the time, everything works as expected, but from time to time, some (or all) services simply stop working. I'm logging all the app exceptions to file, but there are none when it comes to failure. There is also no error in the event logger and the Services manager treats the services as running. I have to stop the services and start them once again to restore the functionality.

This behavior is unpredictable, sometimes it takes a week or a month before it stops working. Also, sometimes the services "dies" all together or only some of them at the same time.

Only thing that crossed my mind is the Timer object. I've been using the System.Timers.Timer and found several forum threads stating it is unreliable as the garbage collector may free the instance. I've tried retaining it using GC.KeepAlive() to no avail. I've followed a few suggestion on moving System.Timers.Timer to System.Threading.Timer but this didn't make any difference either.

Right at the moment, I'm desperate to find out the source of this behavior. Is there any known similar issue? How can I debug it when there is not exception raised and the event log is silent too?

Thank you for any advice that may lead to any solution.

UPDATE: Including the bare-boned code of the current state:

```
private System.Threading.Timer timerPublish = null;
private bool timerDelegateMethodRunning = false;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    SetupTimer();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    if (timerPublish != null)
    {
        timerPublish.Dispose();
    }
}

public void SetupTimer()
{
    if (timerPublish != null)
    {
        timerPublish.Dispose();
    }
    TimerCallback callbackMethod = new TimerCallback(this.timerPublish_Elapsed);
    timerPublish = new System.Threading.Timer(callbackMethod, null, 5000, 5000);
}

void timerPublish_Elapsed(Object stateInfo)
{
    if (timerDelegateMethodRunning)
    {
        return;
    }
    timerDelegateMethodRunning = true;

    try
    {
        // Processing code here
    }
    finally
    {
        timerDelegateMethodRunning = false;
    }
}
```

UPDATE2: Thank you guys for your insights and advices. I'll try to debug the services on the production server once the issue happens again. I'll report back as soon as I have anything new (probably in several weeks).

Comment: You need to do a lot more investigation before you can ask any questions on this. This is a needle in a haystack. Narrow it done some.

Comment: What investigation do you mean? I've already hit the dead end after the several months of trying to solve it on my own. I'm logging all actions the services perform to the file, every timer tick/elapsed occurrence, etc. It simply stops putting anything at the log file and the service don't work from that point.

Comment: In an effort to isolate your problem, I suggest writing a short program that hopefully reproduces the problem.  If you can get it to reproduce with either Timer class, replace the timer code with something homegrown to see if you can work around the problem.  I suggest a loop with a ten second sleep in a background thread for starters (it's easy).  Alternatively you could use Monitor and Pulse.  If you isolate and reproduce the timer bug, submit this code to the question and possibly as a bug to Microsoft...

Comment: Post the function that starts the timer so we can see how you're using it.

Comment: Gabe, I've just updated the original question with the source code.

Comment: Nate, I may try to create my own thread as a replacement of Timer, but I seriously hope I can manage to make it work with the timer as it is designed to work this way, right? Thanks for good idea anyway.

Comment: How do you know that your code isn't getting stuck in the `// Processing code here` block?

Comment: Gabe: I log every single action in the processing code and in any loop or cycle as well. All DB and/or network requests have the timeout set to 20 seconds at maximum. Also, there is no active CPU usage from these services while they are not responsive. The last clue - if some service dies, it often happens to some other (or all of them) at the same time. System services run well, though.

Comment: OK, then the next obvious step is to wait for this to happen, then attach a debugger and break in to see what's going on.

Comment: Gabe: the thing is this is happens on the production server (without VS installed), I can't seem to reproduce the issue on the development machines. Thanks for another debugging hint anyway.

Comment: Spend some time on Tess's blog I mentioned to learn about how to investigate hang or crash issues. That can broaden your view and let you know what you can do even on production servers. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have a log statement in the `if (timerDelegateMethodRunning)` block? Does it hit?

Comment: Gabe: yes, i'm logging it and no, it don't hit.

Comment: @serb: _"Server doesn't have any performace and resources issues or bottlenecks"_ -- I know it sounds unlikely for a server machine, but could it possibly go into a sleep state? If so, can your service deal with that properly (`OnPowerEvent`)?

Comment: Assuming that the timer is a member of the class and the class is still in scope, it would be a bug for the GC to collect it. Also, there's no particular benefit to switching timers, because `System.Timers.Timer` is just a wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`. Provided that all of your timers are implemented as above, I consider it highly unlikely that the timer is your problem. I would be more likely to suspect a deadlock. Are you using locks, mutexes, or semaphores anywhere in your service?

Comment: Have you tried to enable the Server garbage collector by putting GCServer="True" in your .config file?

Comment: Hi @serb, I know this is an old issue for you, but did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you complicate things? :) Just use the `Timer.Change()` method to trigger the timer again when you are ready.

Also know that any uncaught exceptions in the `WorkerMethod` **will** f*ckup your service.

```
public class YourService
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //run once in 5 seconds.
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(WorkerMethod, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }
    }

    void WorkerMethod(object state)
    {
        // Processing code here

        _worker.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite); //Run again in 5 seconds
    }
}
```

### Update

I saw that you where using `System.Timers.Timer`. The biggest problem with it is that it ***ignores exceptions***. That is, if your code throws an exception and you do not catch it: ***you will never be aware of that exception***. It might very well be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Never draw a conclusion too soon before you know what is the cause of the hangs. There can be various unbelievable factors, but dump analysis or live debugging can tell you the truth,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/10/16/net-hang-debugging-walkthrough.aspx

If you like, you can even open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest a slightly altered pattern for your service, anyway; where we have a `readonly` `Timer`, which, after initial assignment, simply gets *toggled* to run as opposed to the way disposing is occurring at the minute, and also keep our own hard reference to the `TimerCallback`. LAstly, we leave the disposing of objects up the to service itself (at least the long term objects we're bothered about).

Although this pattern may not be a white rabbit from a hat in your case, I can vouch for the reliability of many services constructed in this manner. Therefore, if problems ensue even after implementation of such then I would be highly confident in saying that what follows `// Processing code here` is, in and of itself, problematic.

```
private readonly System.Threading.Timer Timer = null;
private readonly System.Threading.TimerCallback Callback = null;
private readonly int Interval = 5000;

public MyService()
{
    Callback = new TimerCallback(this.timerPublish_Elapsed);
    Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void Start()
{
    Timer.Change(Timespan.Zero, Interval);
}

private void Stop()
{
    Timer.Change(Timeout.Inifinite, Timeout.Inifnite);
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    Stop();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(disposing)
    {
        if(Timer != null)
            Timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```